# How to restore a specific file using a backup in Debian

Tags: debian, tar

I have a file which has become corrupt and is making my machine malfuntion, i have  a system backup as a .tgz file, i want to restore this specific file using the file in the backup, but i dont want restore the whole system with the backup, only the specific file , how would i do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/168795/how-do-i-extract-a-specific-file-from-a-tar-archive

Comment: @Worthwelle: Either find a duplicate on this site or copy the answer.